# Can candy people create candy people?

Tags: adventure-time

It seems Princess Bubblegum can create candy people.  Is that out of ordinary things and science?  or does she need a little bit of starter candy person like sourdough bread?

Regardless, if PB were to be hit by a bus and killed tomorrow, is there anyone in the candy kingdom that could create new candy people?

Comment: We can't really say that she's the only person, because so much of Ooo is a mystery.  She's the only person *we know of* that can make candy people, but she's just one of several offspring of the Mother Gum.

Comment: Didn't Lemongrab and the other Lemongrab create the lemon people?

Comment: @lfurini They used the formula from PB. She erased it from their mind(s) later, after they used it to create a third world totalitarian government.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bubblegum is the only person we know of who can create candy people from basic materials.

She does this with a [scientific formula](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Candy_life) (and possibly a bit of magic), and doesn't need a starter (though she can use their 'candy DNA' to create clones). She creates them from inert candy, as shown in [*All Your Fault*](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Neddy) and subsequent episodes, and thus far is the only person to show this knowledge, aside from the Lemongrabs -- and their memory of the formula was removed in the aforementioned episode.

However, much of Ooo is still unknown to us, and Bubblegum herself is but one child of [The Mother Gum](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Gum), itself a wad of mutated bubblegum. She has a brother, [Neddy](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Neddy), and she is said to have other relatives -- all likely descended from the Gum.  This Gum is the only other source of Candy People that we know of.

[image: The Candy Life Formula]

All that said, PB is not the only science-minded person in Ooo and is likely to have a contigency plan, in case she should meet her demise.  The formula itself is written out, others know of it and it's simple enough for a Lemongrab to do -- so it would only be a matter of time before someone else took up the formula after PB was gone.

Recent events have further shown that Candy is a primary element in the Adventure Time universe. Candy people -- or, at least, *one* candy person at a time -- have been generated to maintain the balance throughout history, serving as the Candy Elemental. Thus, it would appear that there must always be a candy person, and *the universe* will create new candy people to fill in the gap whenever there isn't one.

[image: Candy Elemental]

Comment: She botched up her contingency plan in an epic way on the episode *Goliad*. I think she gave up the plan after that.